# Disabling zoomControl in Mappa.js

Tags: javascript, plugins, leaflet, maps

I'm building a site using the Mappa.js library (specifically the leaflet tilemap). I want to use this map as a background for a web-app, but I do not want the zoom controls which are visible in the top. After some research, it seems like this can be disabled in the default leaflet.js by setting zoomControl to false, but this isn't working in Mappa. Help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it in the CSS manually like this:

```css
.leaflet-control-zoom {
        display: none;
      }
```